# Sort an object on indices of an array in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, lodash

OK so given this input (other properties have been stripped for brevity):

```
var names = [{
    name: 'Michael'
}, {
    name: 'Liam'
}, {
    name: 'Jake'
}, {
    name: 'Dave'
}, {
    name: 'Adam'
}];
```

I'd like to sort them by another array's indices, and if they aren't in that array, sort alphabetically.

```
var list = ['Jake', 'Michael', 'Liam'];
```

Giving me an output of:

```
Jake, Michael, Liam, Adam, Dave
```

I've tried using lo-dash but it's not quite right:

```
names = _.sortBy(names, 'name');
names = _.sortBy(names, function(name) {
    var index = _.indexOf(list, name.name);
    return (index === -1) ? -index : 0;
});
```

as the output is:

```
Jake, Liam, Michael, Adam, Dave
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Why `Adam` then `Dave`, how did you sort that out?

Comment: i hope you are aware that there is a function called sort() within javascript and it can sort your array alphabetically ! so the problem now is to move your elements into another array ?

list.sort();
will output

Adam, Dave,Jake, Michael, Liam

Comment: @elclanrs - "if they aren't in that array, sort alphabetically", so in other terms the whole array is sorted alphabetically but those three keys come first if that makes sense. Yes, I am aware of `sort()` although I was already using lodash in the project so it doesn't matter to me to use a native method over the (in my opinion, neater) lodash one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.  `return (index === -1) ? -index : 0;` is the problem.

Following your approach, it should look like this:

```
names = _.sortBy(names, 'name')

var listLength = list.length;

_.sortBy(names, function(name) {
    var index = _.indexOf(list, name.name);
    // If the name is not in `list`, put it at the end
    // (`listLength` is greater than any index in the `list`).
    // Otherwise, return the `index` so the order matches the list.
    return (index === -1) ? listLength : index;
});
```